# Why I got syntax error while I enable strict warning (performance penalty) in Firefox bug?

Tags: firefox, firebug, performance-testing

I have build a website run heavy ajax and I'm really care about performance after I enable Strict warning(performance penalty) in firebug it shown me a lot of warning from **system** and **jquery2.2.3** as below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the option *Strict Warnings (performance penalty)* means that you will also get JavaScript warnings, which are hints about correct usage, though they may not have any effect on the execution of the code.

Examples for this are already shown in your screenshot, like references to undefined variables or using a single equal sign in a statement, which may be a comparison.

Example causing such messages:

```
while (item = array[i]) {
  ...
}
```

In this case `item` is not declared via `var` or `let` before a value is assigned to it, so you'll get a "reference to undefined property" warning. And an assignment is used within the `while` condition, which will cause a "test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?" warning.

jQuery and other libraries make a lot of use of such constructs. That's why you see so many messages related to it.

The logs marked with `<System>` are coming from browser internal code and can be ignored by you. To see them you must also have *Show Chrome Errors* or *Show Chrome Messages*.

Comment: Those messages can come from foreign code or your one. At the right side of each message there's a source link telling you where the error is located.

Answer (score 0):

Using strict means browser will check many things like if variable is initialized before use. There is no syntax error etc